# Inference of Mixtral 8x7b on multiple GPUs with pipeline

Tags: python, pytorch, pipeline, large-language-model

I run Mixtral 8x7b on two GPUs (RTX3090 & A5000) with pipeline. I can load the model in GPU memories, it works fine, but inference is very slow. When I run `nvidia-smi`, there is not a lot of load on GPUs. But the motherboard RAM is full (>128Gb) and a CPU reach 100% of load. I feel that the model is loaded in GPU, but inference is done in the CPU.

Here is my code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig
import time

import torch
from accelerate import init_empty_weights, load_checkpoint_and_dispatch

t1= time.perf_counter()

model_id = "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, device_map="auto")

t2= time.perf_counter()
print(f"Loading tokenizer and model: took {t2-t1} seconds to execute.")
# Create a pipeline
code_generator = pipeline('text-generation', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

t3= time.perf_counter()
print(f"Creating piepline: took {t3-t2} seconds to execute.")


# Generate code for an input string
while True:
  print("\n=========Please type in your question=========================\n")
  user_content = input("\nQuestion: ") # User question
  user_content.strip()
  t1= time.perf_counter()
  generated_code = code_generator(user_content, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id, max_new_tokens=20)[0]['generated_text']
  t2= time.perf_counter()
  print(f"Inferencing using the model: took {t2-t1} seconds to execute.")
  print(generated_code)
```

Any idea why inference is so long (>300s)

Comment: did you check that the tensors were indeed on the gpu?

Comment: @Ivan How can I check it?

Comment: If you're looking to run inference, you probably want to use an inference server like VLLM which will handle things like multiple GPUs and kv caching

Answer (score 2):

Your two GPU cards have 24 GB of GPU memory each, right?

That would be a total of 48 GB. Mixtral, as you load it in your code above, requires around 100 GB of GPU memory. device_map="auto" is loading everything, that does not fit into the GPU memory, in to your RAM. And that is making your inference slow.

On their model card, you'll find code to load the model in Lower precision (8-bit & 4-bit). This will reduce the GPU memory needed by a lot and harms the quality only by a little:
https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1

In a discussion thread on their model card I found this:

- In 4-bits -> 180 trillion bits, that's 22.5GB of VRAM required
- in 8-bits -> 45GB of VRAM
- in half-precision -> 90GB of VRAM required